# Array with key that holds multple info needs to be filtered into a id name etc

Tags: php, symfony

I am using a api call to get info of holders of domains

But the api returns a array with a key that holds id,name,company etc... in one key

example

```
array (
[0] => 4432;name;companyname;adress;email;city,
[1] => 4432;name;companyname;adress;email;city 
)
```

and i need it seperated like this and not one long key with all the info

```
array (0 => array ([id] => 4432, [name] => name, [company] => companyname))
```

it doenst have to be a array if i atleast can filter the id name etc

Laurence

Comment: Hmm...something's off here. Either that API is horribly designed, you're not calling the proper end-point or not calling it with the right parameters. Does this API have some sort of documentation?

Comment: @Andrew i am calling the right end of the api my boss gave me this api to work with. and yes the api is bad. also i have read the documentation and there is no other way to call holders the use the function getholders that returns the array above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = explode(';',$string);
```